# Hide/remove js-view-dom-id in just one specific view

Tags: views, 8, theming

I found, that the div with the id "js-view-dom-id" comes from views-view.html.twig. As I want to render one view output without any of Drupals HTML markup, I already hunted down the contextual links, which I can turn of for a specific view. Then I set the view format to an unused format, and removed all unwanted HTML markup from this views template as well.

Now I get plain {{ content.field_x.0 }}-output from this view. The only element left I need to get rid of is before mentioned "js-view-dom-id". I could remove this from views-view.html.twig, but then I would remove it from all views.

Is there any way to remove this markup for only one specific view? To be precise, I am using a custom content view mode, if that makes any difference.

Thank you very much in advance!

@edit:

Twig in views-view.html.twig looks like this:

```
{%
set classes = [
dom_id ? 'js-view-dom-id-' ~ dom_id,
]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}></div>
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
{% if view mode is xy %}
// Do nothing
{%  else %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily create an override for `views-view.html.twig` which will only apply to a single View.

Taking the example from [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.8.x):

> View, named foobar. Style: unformatted. Row style: Fields. Display: Page.
>
> - views-view--foobar--page.html.twig
> - views-view--page.html.twig
> - views-view--foobar.html.twig
> - views-view.html.twig

So if your View is called "articles", you can use `views-view--articles.html.twig` to override the template for the whole View, `views-view--articles--page.html.twig` to target just a display named `page` for the same view, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works flawlessly! Sorrily I can't mark your anser as the right one, due to not having enough reputation here.